# Multiple UpdatePanel in aspx page, with timer control in one UpdatePanel - network utilization

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have one .aspx page with one ScriptManager and two separate update panel e.g. UpdatePanelTimer, UpdatePanelDetails.

UpdatePanelTimer contains one Timer control with interval of 5 seconds and two Labels for display status, and UpdatePanelDetails contains some controls like TextBox/Dropdowns and Labels to display relevant data.

In both Update Panel the UpdateMode="Conditional". On each timer tick one serverside function execute and update status in Label of UpdatePanelTimer.

All working perfect but when check Inspect option in Google Chrome/Firefox then under Network option in Inspect on every timer tick its showing 9kb use for xhr, incase remove/disable all control of UpdatePanelDetails then on each timer tick its showing 1kb use for xhr!

In this code using AsyncPostBackTrigger for Timer control in UpdatePanelTimer but maybe it use both UpdatePanel data on every interval.

In actual scenario this UpdatePanelDetails contains around 150kb details with both controls and data, due to this server network utilization shows very high.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        
<div id="header" class="splita">
    <div style="width: 100%">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelTimer" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="5000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Enabled="True" EnableViewState="true"></asp:Timer>
                <asp:Label ID="lblstatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblduration" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="mainpnl" class="splitb">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelDetails" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"  ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="row">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
            <div>
            <asp:Label ID="L1" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="labelcs"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="T1" runat="server" CssClass="txtbx" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div>
            <asp:Label ID="L2" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="labelcs"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="T2" runat="server" CssClass="txtbx" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div>
            <asp:Label ID="L3" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="labelcs"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="T3" runat="server" CssClass="txtbx" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div>
            <asp:Label ID="L4" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="labelcs"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="T4" runat="server" CssClass="txtbx" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
        </div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. You turn off controls and save 8Kb (KB?); in scenario with data it's 150Kb. Plus everything that's added means a larger viewstate which can account for a lot.

Comment: Yes correct, actually need to refresh only timer update panel which may be take hardly 1kb, and in realtime its refreshing only timer update panel and data update panel remains as it is but in network utilization its using both update panel size e.g. 8kb in testing and 150kb in actual application. Hope its clarify now.

Comment: The thing about asp.net-ajax IIRC is that there is *always* a full postback. I've seen posts that say otherwise but I think they're wrong. A full postback always occurs, but only the updatepanel content is updated.

Comment: Ok it means the behavior is correct we need to change structure accordingly. Thanks wazz.